when i execute my python file in vscode the output is python file location
for some reason after installing pytorch and transformer into my python library, whenever i run code in vscode the output is:
C:\Users\User\Desktop\bugo>C:/Users/User/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python311/python.exe c:/Users/User/Desktop/bugo/main.py

even if try to create other python file and write
print("hello world")

the output still will be like this
C:\Users\User\Desktop\New Folder>C:/Users/User/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python311/python.exe c:/Users/User/Desktop/New Folder/test.py

i tried to reinstall python many times including newer and older versions of python, i also tried to change interpreter into PS but the output still was python file location, only thing that makes me intensified is that i also get this type of output in pycharm too

What command are you executing to run the application?

whenever i run code in vscode the output is ... Is that the output, or is that the command that you typed?

@JohnGordon yes it is output

I suspect this is not a python problem at all -- you've made a mistake in configuring vs code.

@JohnGordon which configuration shall i check ?

One of your paths includes a space. Any such path must be inside double quotes
